# Model a serial format in the type system, like Servant

Tags: haskell, serialization, type-level-computation, servant

I'm working on an API integration that ignores the existence of XML or JSON in favor of just appending character data. (The [Metro2](http://www.cdiaonline.org/Metro2/content.cfm?ItemNumber=853) format, if interested)

I'm simplifying, but imagine that a person needs to be serialized like this:

- At pos 0, 4 chars: Number of bytes in the message
- At pos 5: 6 chars: `"PERSON"` hard coded
- At pos 11: 20 chars: Name, left-aligned and space-padded
- At pos 21: 8 chars: Birthday, `YYYYMMDD`
- At pos 29: 3 chars: Age, right-aligned and zero-padded

Numeric fields are always right-aligned and zero-padded. Text fields are always left-aligned and space padded.

For example:

```
"0032PERSONDAVID WILCOX        19820711035"
```

Can I express this in the type system? Like what [servant](http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/ApiType.html) does? Something like this?

```
newtype ByteLength = ByteLength Int
newtype Age = Age Int
-- etc

type PersonMessage
     = Field ByteLength '0
    :| Field "PERSON" '5
    :| Field Name '11
    :| Field Date '21
    :| Field Age '29

-- :| is a theoretical type operator, like :> in servant
-- the number is the expected offset
-- the length of the field is implicit in the type
```

Can I statically check that my implementation of the serialization matches the type?

Can I statically check that the offset of the 3rd field (`Name`) is `11`? That the lengths of the preceding fields add up to 11? I'm assuming no, since that seems like it would require full dependent type support.

Is this on the right track?

```
instance ToMetro Age where
   -- get the length into the type system using a type family?
   field = Numeric '3

   -- express how this is encoded. Would need to use the length from the type family. Or if that doesn't work, put it in the constructor.
   toMetro age = Numeric age
```

*Update:* Example of a function I would like to statically validate:

```
personToMetro :: Person -> PersonMessage
personToMetro p = error "Make sure that what I return is a PersonMessage"
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a function that you want to get more static guarantees out of? Like the left-hand side and type signature at least

Comment: Just added an example. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give you some inspiration, just do what Servant does and have different types for the different combinators you support:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Seriavant where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy
import Data.List (stripPrefix)

data Skip (n :: Nat) = Skip deriving Show
data Token (n :: Nat) = Token String deriving Show
data Lit (s :: Symbol) = Lit deriving Show

data (:>>) a b = a :>> b deriving Show
infixr :>>

class Deserialize a where
    deserialize :: String -> Maybe (a, String)

instance (KnownNat n) => Deserialize (Skip n) where
    deserialize s = do
        (_, s') <- trySplit (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)) s
        return (Skip, s')

instance (KnownNat n) => Deserialize (Token n) where
    deserialize s = do
        (t, s') <- trySplit (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)) s
        return (Token t, s')

instance (KnownSymbol lit) => Deserialize (Lit lit) where
    deserialize s = do
        s' <- stripPrefix (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy lit)) s
        return (Lit, s')

instance (Deserialize a, Deserialize b) => Deserialize (a :>> b) where
    deserialize s = do
        (x, s') <- deserialize s
        (y, s'') <- deserialize s'
        return (x :>> y, s'')

trySplit :: Integer -> [a] -> Maybe ([a], [a])
trySplit 0 xs = return ([], xs)
trySplit n (x:xs) = do
    (xs', ys) <- trySplit (n-1) xs
    return (x:xs', ys)
trySplit _ _ = Nothing
```

Yeah so this is quite spartan, but it already allows you to do

```
type MyFormat = Token 4 :>> Lit "PERSON" :>> Skip 1 :>> Token 4

testDeserialize :: String -> Maybe MyFormat
testDeserialize = fmap fst . deserialize
```

which works like this:

> ```
> *Seriavant> testDeserialize "1"
> Nothing
> *Seriavant> testDeserialize "1234PERSON Foo "
> Just (Token "1234" :>> (Lit :>> (Skip :>> Token "Foo ")))
> ```

**EDIT**: Turns out I completely misread the question, and Sean is asking for serialization, not deserialization... But of course we can do that as well:

```
class Serialize a where
    serialize :: a -> String

instance (KnownNat n) => Serialize (Skip n) where
    serialize Skip = replicate (fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)) ' '

instance (KnownNat n) => Serialize (Token n) where
    serialize (Token t) = pad (fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)) ' ' t

instance (KnownSymbol lit) => Serialize (Lit lit) where
    serialize Lit = symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy lit)

instance (Serialize a, Serialize b) => Serialize (a :>> b) where
    serialize (x :>> y) = serialize x ++ serialize y

pad :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
pad 0 _x0 xs = xs
pad n x0 (x:xs) = x : pad (n-1) x0 xs
pad n x0 [] = replicate n x0
```

(of course this has horrible performance with all this `String` concatenation etc. but that's not the point here)

> ```
> *Seriavant> serialize ((Token "1234" :: Token 4) :>> (Lit :: Lit "FOO") :>> (Skip :: Skip 2) :>> (Token "Bar" :: Token 10))
> "1234FOO  Bar       "
> ```

Of course, if we know the format, we can avoid those pesky type annotations:

```
type MyFormat = Token 4 :>> Lit "PERSON" :>> Skip 1 :>> Token 4

testSerialize :: MyFormat -> String
testSerialize = serialize
```

> ```
> *Seriavant> testSerialize (Token "1234" :>> Lit :>> Skip :>> Token "Bar")
> "1234PERSON Bar "
> ```

Comment: This is sweet, and super helpful, thanks! To be clear, I don't need to deserialize this format, only serialize it.

Comment: @SeanClarkHess yeah maybe I should try reading questions next time before answering them ;)

Comment: So I see how to use the Nat values at runtime. Is there any way to use them to statically check that the offsets line up? (See in my question, above)

Comment: The trick I use here is to store the offsets implicitly in the type: the width of every part is static and knowable from the type alone; and the offset is simply the sum of the width of all previous parts.