# Couldn't match kind '*' with 'Nat'

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

I'm trying to create a type that guarantees that a string is less than N characters long.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Symbol, Nat, KnownNat, natVal, KnownSymbol, symbolVal)
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as Text
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))

data TextMax (n :: Nat) = TextMax Text
  deriving (Show)

textMax :: KnownNat n => Text -> Maybe (TextMax n)
textMax t
  | Text.length t <= (fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)) = Just (TextMax t)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

This gives the error:

```
src/Simple/Reporting/Metro2/TextMax.hs:18:50: error:
• Couldn't match kind ‘*’ with ‘Nat’
  When matching the kind of ‘Proxy’
• In the first argument of ‘natVal’, namely ‘(Proxy :: Proxy n)’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)’
  In the second argument of ‘(<=)’, namely
    ‘(fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n))’
```

I don't understand this error. Why doesn't it work? [I've used almost this exact same code to get the natVal of n in other places and it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667682/model-a-serial-format-in-the-type-system-like-servant).

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Side remark: by turning on the `PolyKinds` extension, ghc is more lenient with the idea of a poly-kinded `Proxy` and the error message becomes different and makes it a lot clearer that it's a typical `ScopedTypeVariables` issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need an explicit `forall` in the signature of `textMax`, so that `ScopedTypeVariables` kicks in and the `n` in the `Proxy n` annotation becomes the same `n` in the `KnownNat n` constraint:

```
textMax :: forall n. KnownNat n => Text -> Maybe (TextMax n)
textMax t
  | Text.length t <= (fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)) = Just (TextMax t)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```